# Why does form submission convert submitted data into query parameters in the URL bar?

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 5, Does it affect things?

Also, is there a way to prevent this?

Before people ask me about not giving code in the question, I hope it's irrelevant as this is a general theoretical question.

Comment: Have you used <form method="POST">. Without using this it will be treated as a GET request and parameters would be added in URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the form is submitted using "GET" method instead of "POST" method. :p

e.g:-

```
<form method="POST" action="link.php"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically it's determined by the method you use, GET will place items int he url while POST sends them using the header so they are not seen if I remember correctly.